# $ is not defined even though I'm definitely loading it first

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, dependencies

This is my html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src='./JS-LIBS/jquery-2.0.0-min.js'></script>
    <script src='./app/app.js'></script>

</head>
<body>
    <h1>HELLO WORLD!</h1>
<h3 id="date">1-1-1697</h3>
<div id="main-content">
    <p>This is my hello world post!</p>
</div>
<div id="comments">
    <h3>Comments</h3>
    <p>This is stupid</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

The error message in chrome developer tools console is "Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined". This is app.js

```
$(document).on('ready', function(){
var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:3333');
socket.on('populate', function(data){
    $.each(data, function(index, datum){
        $('h1').text(datum.title);
        $('#date').text(datum.date_published);
        $('#main-content p').text(datum.content);    
    }); 
});
```

});

I'm running it through node.js as a local host on ubuntu if it matters. There does not appear to be an error loading jquery by the way.

Comment: Do the Chrome developer tools report any 404 errors?

Comment: This is the entire console.log: Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/plain: "http://localhost:3333/JS-LIBS/jquery-2.0.0-min.js". index.html:4
Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/plain: "http://localhost:3333/app/app.js". index.html:4
Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined app.js:1
(anonymous function) app.js:1

Comment: Try this one <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: Yea that's a weird one.  Since it's *interpreted* as a script, it should still work.  @UsualSuspect's recommendation is worth trying.

Comment: or try it by explicitly mentioning "type" in the script tag
<script type="text/javascript" src=".."></script>

Comment: @UsualSuspect that actually fixed it. Any idea why?

Comment: Sometimes we need to mention the type in the script tag explicitly if it doesn't work in certain environments.

Comment: Because your localhost server is not configured properly and it is serving `.js` files with the wrong MIME type.

Comment: no it wasn't giving me an error that it couldn't find the file. Thanks all.